# How to find the common denominator with multiple variables

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, fractions

Find $\frac{zf^{'}(z)}{f(z)}$, where $-1 \leq \alpha \leq 0 $ and $0< v < 1$

Given:
$f(z)= \frac{1}{\pi}(-\log (1-vz)+ \alpha \log(1-vz^{-1}))$

and $f^{'}(z)= \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{v}{1-vz} + \frac{\alpha v}{z^{2}-vz}\right)$

$$\implies \frac{zf^{'}(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{z(\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{v}{1-vz} + \frac{\alpha v}{z^{2}-vz}\right)}{\frac{1}{\pi}(-\log (1-vz)+ \alpha \log (1-vz^{-1}))} = \frac{z\left(\frac{v}{1-vz} + \frac{\alpha v}{z^{2}-vz}\right)}{(-\log (1-vz)+ \alpha \log(1-vz^{-1}))}$$

Let $z=e^{it}$ and consider $\zeta=e^{it}$ and $0 \leq t<2 \pi$.

$$\frac{zf^{'}(z)}{f(z)}\implies \frac{(\frac{v \alpha}{e^{it}(1-ve^{-it})}+ \frac{ve^{it}}{1-ve^{it}})}{(-\log (1-ve^{it})+ \alpha \log(1-v-e^{it}))}$$

Where $e^{it}= \cos t+i \sin t$ and $e^{-it}=\cos t-i\sin t$.

$$\frac{zf^{'}(z)}{f(z)} \implies \frac{(\frac{v \alpha}{\cos t+i \sin t(1-v \cos t-i \sin t)}+ \frac{v \cos t+i \sin t}{1-v \cos t+i \sin t})}{-\log (1-v \cos t+i \sin t)+ \alpha \log(1-v \cos t-i \sin t)}$$

Now we can compute for $\frac{zf^{'}(z)}{f(z)}$:

$$\frac{zf^{'}(z)}{f(z)} \implies
\frac{(\frac{v \alpha}{ \cos t+i \sin t(1-v \cos t-i \sin t)}+ \frac{v \cos t+i \sin t}{1-v \cos t+i \sin t})}{-\log (1-v \cos t+i \sin t)+ \alpha \log (1-v \cos t-i \sin t)}$$

Hi there I've been working on this problem for a while and I have come to a halt. I've been stuck trying to figure out on how to combine the common denominator.  I was wondering if anybody can assistance me on this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time for your cooperation.

Comment: I have attempted to understand your derivation after fixing the formatting a bit, but I get stuck because I read there $f'(z)= \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{v}{1-vz} + \frac{\alpha v}{z^{2}-vz}\right)$ and then $f'(z)= \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{v \alpha}{z^{2}(1-vz^{-1})}\right)+ \frac{v}{1-vz}$.  Wolfram Alpha does not like the first of these, suggesting that the right answer is ${1\over\pi}\left({v\over 1-zv}+{\alpha v\over z^2(1-v/z)}\right)$. This is close to  the second, but no cigar.

Comment: Suggestion:  redo your calculations checking them step by step with Wolfram Alpha.  Then, if you're still confused, ask another question.